# ui:repeat or p:dataTable not working with list<>

Tags: jsf

I have this method:

```
public List<RequestItemVO> getRequestItem() {
        //compiled code
        throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}
```

When I try this:

```
<ui:repeat value=#{requestController.backing.requestVO.requestItem} var="item">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
<ui:repeat>
```

I don't have any results, nothing is generated on my HTML (checked the source).

But if I do this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{requestController.backing.requestVO.requestItem.get(0).getMaterial().getDescription()}"/>
```

I have the material description.

Why it is not working on the `<ui:repeat>` or `<p:dataTable>`? I need it to work there to list all request items.

Comment: What is that `throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");`? It seems that there's means of AOP or something and that the `iterator()` of the injected list doesn't do its job properly while the `get()` does its job properly. At least, with normal code it's supposed to work just fine.

Comment: @BalusC it is a compiled .jar and when I click the method, netbeans show me this but I think it is working correctly since it returns me the value on the the second code I've pasted

Comment: @BalusC it's just what Netbeans shows when it doesn't find any attached sources to the file, equivalent to Eclipse's Class File Editor "Source not found".

Comment: @Daniel, the value attribute of your `h:outputText` has a typo, it is closing the quote before closing the bracket. Does your real code have this problem too?

Comment: No, typo, sorry. Updated

Comment: Okay. What if you create a basic view+model example in playground project wherein you create the list yourself? E.g. `public List<String> getList() { return Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"); }` with `<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">#{item}</ui:repeat>`. Does it still fail?

Comment: @BalusC it worked only outside the `p:panelGrid`

Comment: Uhm, how's that related to the problem? Were you trying to generate cells of a panelgrid?

Comment: @BalusC **correction** it didn't work because it was not inside an row column, inside it it works, so you think the problem is with my object?

Comment: @BalusC it works with your suggestion, not with my object

Comment: Okay then it's a problem in the `getRequestItem()` implementation and how it's been prepared. Hard to tell without seeing the concrete code.

Comment: Problem solved based on your suggestion @BalusC. I was trying to user `ui:repeat` without creating the `p:row` and `p:column`. If possible, answer wwith your suggestion of code.

Comment: Hmm I can do, but that wouldn't explain why it worked with `get(0)`. Or did you put that part correctly in a p:row/p:column?

Comment: It was only inside the `p:column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments you were attempting to use `<ui:repeat>` inside a `<p:panelGrid>`. This would only have worked if you have wrapped it in a `<p:row><p:column>`. Inside a `<p:dataTable>` this would only have worked if you have wrapped it in a `<p:column>`.